# Concept behind declaring variables in each submodule instead of declaring it once in parent and reusing it in terraform

Tags: terraform

I come from development background. I am newbie to terraform. I was looking into the ways to pass parent module variable/locals to submodule. The purpose behind it to declare all the variables in one place.
For example I want to declare aws region local value into parent module and pass it to network submodule which uses 'vpc' module from aws provider.
I am interested into both why and how here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules have to declare input variables. Modules do not get access to parent modules input variables by default. They have to be declared as input variables in the modules, and then the values explicitly passed into the modules from the parent.

There are no "global" variables in Terraform.

Think of modules in Terraform like functions in programming. Functions declare what parameters you can pass into them, and when you call those functions you have to explicitly pass the parameters into them.